# Can I redirect .NET method calls to a new method at runtime?

Tags: .net, hook, detours

Suppose I have the following .NET classes:

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

and

```
public class D
{
    public void N()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

These 2 classes reside in different namespaces, in different assemblies.  Is there a way to cause all call to `C.M()` to 'redirect' automatically to `D.N()`?  So, the calling method things its invoking `C.M`, but in reality, `D.N` is what actually gets called, with any parameters that `C.M` would have taken.  It doesn't matter if this happens for all instantiations of the class, or just for one specific object.

MS Research has the [Detours Library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) that can do something very similar for normal Win32 DLL exports.  I'm looking for a way to do this with a .NET method.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has created a managed equivalent to Detours called [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/). The only thing I'm not sure of is the licensing; it is intended for testing (as part of Pex).

Dependency injection requires modifying the source; PostSharp requires modifying the binary; but Moles can be done dynamically at runtime.

---

**Update**: Moles was moved into Visual Studio itself; it is available in the Enterprise edition and is now called [Microsoft Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes).

Comment: Moles looks promising.  A quick test should determine whether its technically appropriate for this usage or not.  If so, I'll accept this.

Comment: Moles is freely available for commercial use by MSDN licensees - hooray!

Comment: do you know the modern alternative/successor to Moles? is seems `Moles` is a thing of the past.

Comment: @T.Todua: Moles was moved into Visual Studio itself; it is available in the Enterprise edition and is now called [Microsoft Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes).

Comment: @StephenCleary maybe i misunderstood, as I thought of it as being independent helper/library/framework, to help doing things runtime, and i am not clear how integration in Visual Studio will achieve the result, moreover only for Enterprise Users. 
So, to ask in two words - is there any up-to-date free way to do what OP wanted?

Comment: @T.Todua: I am not aware of any solution that is both well-proven and free.

Answer (score 3):

There are mainly two possible approaches - proxying the objects or hooking the calls.

Proxying can be done using [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) or any similar dynamic proxy framework. Hooking the calls can either be done with aspect oriented programming with something like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) or even by black magic like done by [Isolator](http://site.typemock.com/) (it is designed for unit testing but it can probably be (ab)used like all other technologies)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you could do some IL weaving with [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp).

I did find this nice article on using other tools too : http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2009/02/14/Simple-AOP-call-interception-with-DynamicProxy.aspx

Comment: I'll check out LOOM.NET, mentioned in that blog post.  That also looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)?

Modify C to:

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        if (Override != null) { Override.N(); }
        else {
            ....
        }
    }

    public D Override
}
```

If you need more flexibility, [Extract Interface](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractInterface.html) from class D.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

Please see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/Net-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Codes-on-Run-time

You can do that by modifying the IL code on runtime